# Command to load buffer but not make it current

Tags: buffers, hidden-buffers

I can list buffers with `:ls` and see their load state. I can load all the buffers using `:bufdo e` and a specific buffer using a range, for instance to load only buffer 2 `:2bufdo e`, however this makes buffer 2 the current file, that is I can now see it. Is there a command I can use to ensure a buffer is loaded but not make it current?

For a bit of background see [vim-orgmode issue](https://github.com/jceb/vim-orgmode/issues/293#issuecomment-682375831)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you explain why you need a buffer to be loaded? Whenever you need access to the buffer, Vim would load it at that point anyways... I can't really see why one would need to preload a buffer... Can you expand on that? It's easier to switch to a buffer with `:b 2`, why not just do that? Can you use `:e #` to switch back to the file you were editing after loading buffer 2?

Comment: Also, in the vim-orgmode issue, you mention args and `:argdo`, so is this actually about args that haven't been loaded into buffers yet? Or do you really see them in `:ls` output, but without the flag showing it's loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [`bufload()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#bufload()) and maybe [`bufadd()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#bufadd()).

Usage example:

```
call bufadd('someName')->bufload()
```

The patch [8.1.1610](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.1610) is required.